# Problems with JUnitTest and multiple objects

Tags: java, object, junit4

I'm having trouble getting my JUnitTest to cooperate. I have traced the issue back to the setUp method which creates two instances of an Object of a worker class.

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    company = new Company("New Source");
    company.addEmployee("John", "Smith","Manufacturing");
    company.addEmployee("Bob", "Brown", "Manufacturing");
    company.addEmployee("Harold", "Jones", "Sales");
    company.addEmployee("Betty","Boop", "Design");

    //STUDENT: Create your own instance of company (studentCompany) and add employees.
    //You will use this studentCompany instance in the STUDENT test methods

    // create studentCompany instance and add employees
    studentCompany = new Company("Better Business");
    studentCompany.addEmployee("Barack", "Obama", "Manufacturing");
    studentCompany.addEmployee("George", "Bush Jr", "Sales");
    studentCompany.addEmployee("Bill", "Clinton", "Manufacturing");
    studentCompany.addEmployee("George", "Bush Sr", "Design");
```

Now, in the Unit Test that tests to see if my print function works it expects "John" but actually gets "Barack"

```
public void testPrintCompany() {

        String result = company.printCompany();
        Scanner company = new Scanner(result);
        assertEquals("New Source",company.nextLine()); 
        //extract three Employees
        assertEquals("John", company.next());
        company.nextLine();  //Smith     Position design (rest of line)
        assertEquals("Bob", company.next());
        company.nextLine();  //Brown     Position manufacturing (rest of line)
        assertEquals("Harold",company.next()); //Harold
        company.nextLine();  //Jones     Position Sales (rest of line);
        assertEquals("Betty",company.next());
        company.close();
    }
```

My print function works by using an arraylist like so:

```
String result = ""; // will hold string to return

result=companyName+"\n";  // insert company name in first line

for(int i=0;i < employees.size(); i++){ // for each member of Employee list
    Employee emp = employees.get(i);    // set Employee at Employeelist(i) to emp
    result+= emp.getFirstName() + " " + emp.getLastName() + " Position: " + emp.getPos() +"\n"; // add first, last name and position to line
}
return result; // return line
```

So essentially my code is messing up because when JUnitTest calls setUp, it creates the studentCompany object after the company object and therefore overrides what's in the arrayList, right? How can I fix this?

Comment: `company` and `studentCompany` should have completely different lists of employees. Your test case seems ok. My expectation from this is that there is an error in the `Company` class.

Comment: @BevynQ the test case came from the professor, so it has to be right. I'm almost certain my error lies within my the printCompany method. I'm not entirely sure how I should go about creating several ArrayLists of Company objects, if that's indeed what I have to do.

Comment: The part provided of the print method looks ok. I wonder if employees is declared static. Use a debugger or log the state of employees at the end of setUp() are places you could start.

Comment: @BevynQ YOU GOT IT! Oh my god I can't believe I made employees static -.- Thank you so much